# Simplified Bingo task

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The usual bingo game is 5 on 5. The central cell is free. Balls are consistently obtained (randomly 1-75). The game ends when all the numbers around the free cell are collected. It is necessary to find the probability of victory for each i-th getting of the last necessary ball. It is also necessary to make a winning table so that the expectation of 0.98 \$  $\pm $ 0.01 \$ turns out.

As I understand it, the probability formula is as follows:
$$ P_i=\frac{\binom{N-8}{i-8}}{\binom{N}{i}}=\frac{\binom{75-8}{i-8}}{\binom{75}{i}} $$
However, it is calculated independently of the previous steps, that is, the sum of the probabilities($\sum_{i=0}^n P_i$)!= 1. In the case of such a formula of differences ($ P_{delta}=P_i - P_{i-1} $), the sum of probability($\sum_{i=0}^n P_{delta}$) = 1 is obtained. Why?

Did I understand correctly that the math expectation of a win is made up as $$\sum_{i=0}^n (\text{reward or winning}) * (\text{the probability of winning separately}(P_{delta}))?$$

Thank you for your help!